# Why is "Ihn interessiert nur" using Ihn?

Tags: sentence-structure

In the sentence, “Ihn interessiert nur,was mit verbrechen zu tun hat” why was Ihn used? Should it not be "Er interessiert nur was mit verbrechen zu tun hat?"

Comment: Did you look up *interessieren* in a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Ihn** interessiert nur, was mit Verbrechen zu tun hat.

The subject in this sentence isn't *ihn*, but the whole phrase *was mit Verbrechen zu tun hat*. You can assure that by asking

> **Wer oder was** interessiert ihn nur? — **Was** mit Verbrechen zu tun hat.

So, with that phrase being the subject and in nominative: what's *ihn*? It's the accusative object to the verb *interessieren*, and put into accusative because of that.

> **Wen oder was** interessiert nur, was mit Verbrechen zu tun hat? — Ihn.

The declension of the pronoun *er* is: er/seiner/ihm/**ihn** (nominative/genitive/dative/accusative)

---

To add a bit of explanation to this special case: *Interessieren* is **not** the act of showing interest in someone or something.

Rather, it's the act of **causing interest**. That's why the roles of subject and object may seem reversed to you. It's the same in English but maybe not in your first language.

Comment: Nah. Disagree with last paragraph. It's not the same in English. *I am interested in an action* - is definitely not like *Die Aktion interessiert mich*

Comment: @tofro: It **is** the same, because _es interessiert ihn_ translates to _it interests him_. Your example, _I am interested in_, is translated from _ich interessiere mich für_ or _ich bin interessiert an_.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich So you think _Sport interests me_ is an idiomatic translation of _Sport interessiert mich_?

Comment: *I am interested in* → *Ich bin interessiert an*; *It is interesting to me.* → *Es interessiert mich.*

Comment: @sgf, for this discussion it is not important that it is idiomatic as long as it is grammatical. Still, an example in an Oxford Dictionary is ‘I thought the book might interest Eliot’.